# How do you switch between "free" and "bounded" text boxes in Pixelmator Pro?

Tags: text, page-layout, pixelmator

As per the [official guide](https://www.pixelmator.com/tutorials/contents/add-and-edit-text/), in Pixelmator Pro you can click to create a free text box (which changes size to match what you type) or drag to create a bounded text box (which remains the same size regardless of contents).

Is there a way to switch between these two text modes?

Answer (score 1):

According to Pixelmator support, it is not possible to switch between text box types:

> There isn’t a way to switch a text box type after adding it. The simplest solution would probably be to add a new text box and cut/paste the text from the original one.